# Paypal adaptive payment with Minibrowser

Tags: javascript, paypal

I'm using adaptive payments api with the minibrowser(https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/apdg.js).

I got an error like this.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apps' of undefined at ...

Here is the source code of apdg.js.

```
if (fullpageRedirect) {    
    window.PAYPAL = window.PAYPAL || {};
    PAYPAL.apps = PAYPAL.apps || {}; // Error: PAYPAL is undefined
    ...
}
else {
    if (typeof PAYPAL == 'undefined' || !PAYPAL) {
        var PAYPAL = {}; // bug? If I delete the var keyword then it works. 
    }
    ...
}
```

In addition, I have some questions below.
Who is maintaining the apdg.js? What's the license of the file?
What is www.paypalobjects.com for?
Is it a good idea to make the apdg.js as a internal link(download apdg.js and put it on my own server)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paypal maintains `apdg.js` and I believe `paypalobjects.com` is simply the domain Paypal uses to host their asset files.

I would highly recommend not using Adaptive Payments at all costs though. We integrated with Adaptive Payments because at the time it was the only option (this was before Braintree) and have regretted it ever since.

- Paypal made a breaking change to `apdg.js` with no forewarning and in fact it is still broken. We had to locally host the file and revert the change just to get our integration working again.
- Paypal's IPN mechanism is unreliable at best. We ended up with a huge number of transactions in unknown states and had to come up with hacks to try and bring some semblance of sanity to the process.
- Paypal put Adaptive Payments in limited release in 2016 and even recommend themselves to not create new integrations with it.
- I'm not sure if this is just in regards to Adaptive Payments or Paypal developer support in general, but our experience has been horrendous when when we needed help or basic questions answered.
- In fact our Adaptive Payments integration has been down for over 6 weeks and we have not gotten an ETA or any indication as to what the issue is or when it will be fixed.

Comment: How did you revert it? Where can I get the correct version of apdg.js?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevant to your situation, but in February they hardcorded and disabled non-full page redirect integrations. We re-enabled this by simply undoing the hardcoding of this: https://imgur.com/a/2xxvmDP